# Error while testing Node and NPM by running simple js file

Tags: json, node.js, npm, cygwin

I created a simple javascript file called    `hello.js` which has the code    `console.log('Node is installed!');` As you can see in the screenshot I have installed node and npm. You can see the version in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlfaH.png). I am currently in the directory where my    `hello.json` file resides. Now when I type    `node hello.json` in my cygwin terminal it gives me the following error    `module.js:674
    throw err;
    ^`    `SyntaxError: C:\Users\SAHNN002\Documents\Testing\hello.json: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.Module._extensions..json (module.js:671:27)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3`

I am pretty much new to node js. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: rename your file from .json to .js

Comment: Hey @DennyFerra. Thank you so much. I was saving it as a json file whereas it is a javascript file. It worked. Appreciate your help man.